# Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle scientific proof

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, observables

[Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) states that:

$$\sigma(x)\sigma(  p_x )\ge \frac {\hbar}{2}.$$

What is the scientific proof of this principle?
[Operators Uncertainty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24178/operators-uncertainty)

Comment: If you want a *mathematical* proof, I think the simplest thing you can look at is the Heisenberg-Gabor inequality (Gabor's original paper: [http://www.univie.ac.at/NuHAG/FEI/finalps/CLASSICS/gabor46.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20050302061559/http://www.univie.ac.at/NuHAG/FEI/finalps/CLASSICS/gabor46.pdf), esp. look at the explanation on pg. 432), which essentially states that a function and its Fourier transform cannot both be bounded domain and is easy to prove.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10362/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic not a dupe: the OP is looking for experimental proof as you can deduce from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24116/

Comment: Further discussion has been moved [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6942/discussion-between-annav-and-sklivvz)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The uncertainty principle, in the variance formulation, states that in any quantum state $|\rangle$, the quantity

$$\langle (p-<p>)^2 \rangle \langle (x-\langle x\rangle)^2\rangle \ge {\hbar^2 \over 4} $$

To understand why shifting p and x by their expected value and squaring gives the squared uncertainty, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24178/operators-uncertainty/24185#24185).

The proof is by noting the following

$$ |\langle \psi | \eta \rangle| \le \sqrt{ ||\psi||^2 ||\eta||^2}$$

This is the statement that the dot-product of two vectors is less than the product of their lengths. It is called the "Cauchy Schwartz inequality". For the special case above, defining the operators $P= p-\langle p\rangle$ and $Q=x-\langle x\rangle$ (and squaring both sides),

$$ ( \langle P Q \rangle )^2 \le \langle PP\rangle\langle QQ\rangle $$

Where to see that the above is an instance of Cauchy Schwarz, take:

$$ |\psi\rangle = P|\rangle$$
$$ |\eta\rangle = Q|\rangle$$
While the product PQ can be decomposed into a real and imaginary part

$$ PQ = {1\over 2} (PQ+QP) + {1\over 2} (PQ-QP) $$

The first part is imaginary, because if you take the Hermitian conjugate, it changes sign. The second part is real (this is ultimately because P and Q are real, i.e. Hermitian). The expected value of PQ squared is the square of the imaginary and real parts separately

$$ (\langle P Q \rangle)^2 = {1\over 4} (\langle [P,Q]\rangle)^2 + {1\over 4}(\langle PQ+QP)\rangle)^2 $$

Since both square things are positive, this means that the left hand side is bigger than one quarter the square of the commutator. The commutator is unchanged by the shifting,

$$ [P,Q] = [p,x] = \hbar $$

So that

$$ \langle P^2 \rangle \langle Q^2\rangle \ge (\langle PQ \rangle)^2 \ge {1\over 4} (\langle [P,Q] \rangle)^2 = {\hbar^2 \over 4} $$

The proof is usually given in one line, as directly above, where the Cauchy Schwarz step (first inequality), the imaginary/real part decomposition (second inequality) and the shifted canonical commutation relations (last equality) are assumed internalized by the reader.

This proof appears on Wikipedia, it is used in all QM books, but perhaps this explanation is clearer.

Comment: This is not an answer anymore, after the OP clarified (in a comment) that he's looking for experimental proof. I've changed the question accordingly, but I am not really sure if this answer is appropriate anymore.

Comment: @Sklivvz: Out of curiosity, which of OP's comments are you referring to?

Comment: @Qme http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24116/experimental-proof-of-the-heisenberg-uncertainty-principle/24186#comment55802_24116

Comment: @Qmechanic  Obviously the OP was satisfied with this answer, and he has accepted it. So I dont know what Slivvz is up to by saying it is not an answer anymore. Please leave it as it is. Maybe the change of the question Sklivvz has done is not what the OP wanted to? I thought editing someone else's question such that it changes the meaning of the question is considered rude or at least inappropriate at Physics SE? By no means should this answer be deleted because of this.

Comment: Since the OP was a member of TP.SE and seems not to be active here anymore, it is not possible to ask him about his intention. So if anything should be done at all, I would rather roll back the question such that it fits again with the accepted answer.

Comment: @Dilaton it would then be a dupe of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10362/2451

Answer (score 9):

A wide variety of experiments, of which the [Double Slit experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment) is the most dramatic, can be used to establish that matter is best represented as a wave on microscopic scales.  Once you represent matter as a wave, then it is natural to associate its position with the spread of the wave, and its momentum with the wavelength of the wave.  Once you do this, however, it should be clear that there is a tradeoff between a well defined ''location'' of the wave, and a well defined ``wavelength'' of the wave.  Therefore, one cannot simultaneously precisely define a particle's position and momentum.  Extra precision in one must come with a lost in precision in the other.

Comment: There is no tradeoff when you derive a slit pattern or any edge pattern with a photon/ particle solution. Matter is best represented as a particle because a wave can only account for some of the phenomena. Not only that but a wave cannot realistically be explained or accounted for. No one even offers a description. For example how would you physical describe the wave action of a single photon traveling from a star to Earth? Does it fill the whole universe and if not why not?

Comment: @BillAlsept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet

Comment: The first paragraph and the illustration pretty much describe a photon. I do not see how this could describe a wave considering there are no ends to a waves. Are you saying your wave has some kind of boundary limit? It spreads out but not too far? That does not sound like a wave it sounds more like a local packet of energy like a photon.

Comment: @BillAlsept: it's a localized wave.  The article describes how you can localize a wave.  The whole point of the hiesenberg uncertainty principle is that there's a trade-off between the localization of a particle, and having a well-definied momentum of a wave.  Proper particles in QFTs are neither waves nor particles.

Comment: The uncertainty principle and the wave function don't to count for anything real they are only a good tool for calculating. We know that light really does physically come from there to here. Now tell me how you can localize a light wave in reality.

Comment: @BillAlsept: single photon pheomena, wavelets, laser interference patterns, etc.  There are literally a million experiments.  Because the calculating tools are used to predict pehnomena, and the phenomena are consistent with all known experiments.

Comment: More simply, you have to do some gynmastics to describe compton scattering with a purely wave picture, and you have to do some gynmaistics to explain the double slit experiment with a purely particulate picture.  The problem reconciling these things is exactly why the wave-particle formalism was created.  It's not just people twiddling their thumbs mathematically.

Comment: You do not have to do gymnastics to make the double slit experiment work for particles. All you have to do is except a photon as a real packet of energy. I have already explained one way to derive any slit experiment on my website listed at the top of my page. There are no ways to physically explain a slit experiment with a wave. Because no one can explain what a light wave really is.

Comment: @BillAlsept: A wave is a sum of sinsuoidal amplitudes.  That's it.  And any explanation of the double slit experiment will have to fall back on this, because the output of the double slit experiment is a sum of sinsuoidal amplitudes.  You can play semantic games all you want, but that's just what the experiment does.  And the mathematics of the double slit experiment (minus the wave collapse stuff) is completely identical to the mathematics of a water wave incident on a double slit.

Comment: and "a real packet of energy" IS A WAVELET.  A WAVELET IS A TYPE OF WAVE.  We write examples using monochromatic plane waves for simplicity, not because anyone believes that they are the sole solutions to wave equations, or are physically realizable states.

Comment: waves cannot account for all the phenomena of light. The number one argument the wave offers is to claim that particles cannot derive the double slit experiment so waves most be the answer??  This. Is not true and any slit experiment can be derived with particles both mathematically and physically. A wave cannot even be physically described. For example how big is the wave, what's its boundaries. If a single photon traveled from a star to hear how big were the trillions of waves? Did they all oscillate in every direction throughout the whole universe just for one Photon?

Comment: @BillAlsept: the interference phenomena that can be derived from light are too numerous to describe.  And all of your issue scan be solved with envelopes on fields.  In addition to the double slit problem, you have single slit interference, diffraction, thin film diffraction, light bending, the optical resolution around a narrow aperture, interferometry and so on and so on.

Comment: And a photon is both a wave and a particle.  In quantum mechanics, the two concepts are not distinct.

Comment: all of The light phenomena you describe can be derived from a particle bases as I have described. Your so-called envelope field just passes it on to another word. What is your field made of and how does that account for all the phenomena if it is not photons?

Comment: @BillAlsept: Quantum particles are wave-particles.  They have wave nature and particle nature.  You're the one redefining words.  Wave envelopes and wavelets are hundred year old physics concepts.

Comment: What is the field made of if not photons? How is a force transferred from point A to B? What is a wave made of if not photons?

Comment: @BillAlsept: THE PHOTONS <b>ARE</b> WAVE-PARTICLES.  THERE IS NO "MADE OF".  You are confusing a thing and its representation.

Comment: And, once again, none of these experiments work with claassical particles.  If you redefine the rules enough to be consistent with the experiment, you have a quantum particle, whihc has many of the features of a classical wave.    And that's the key point, the classical notions of particle and wave become incoherent at the quantum level.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you mean by **scientific proof**. A hypotheses can be **validated** by **scientific method**. Its not **proof** as in mathematics. Because physics does not deal with abstract mathematical ideas which can be **proved** by following some predefined axioms and rules. Which has nothing to do with **observation**.

If uncertainty principle is taken as truth then physical phenomenon regarding subatomic particles can be explained and to some extent predicated by  quantum mechanical framework.

Comment: In this case though, the Uncertainty Principle is a physical consequence of the mathematics used to describe physics (operators of position and momentum and their relation: the Fourier transform). So one could argue that within the framework of Quantum theory, there is definite proof of the uncertainty principle. The theory is then validated by various experiments, which can only go as far as to (not) contradict theory.

Answer (score 2):

For an observable $A$, write $\langle A\rangle$ for the expected value of $A$ and $\Delta A$ for its standard deviation (so that $\langle A\rangle$ and $\Delta A$ both depend on the current state $\phi$).   If $\langle A\rangle=0$ then $\Delta A=\langle A^2\rangle$.

Now given two observables $A$ and $B$, adjust so $\langle A\rangle=\langle B\rangle=0$.  Let $\phi$ be the current state and $x$ an arbitrary real number.

Then
$$\eqalign{
0\phantom{3}\le\phantom{3}&\Big\langle (A+ixB)\phi,(A+ixB)\phi\Big\rangle \cr
&= \overline{\phi} A^2 \phi + x^2 \overline{\phi} B^2 \phi -ix\overline{\phi} BA \phi
+ix \overline{\phi} AB\phi \cr
&= \langle A^2\rangle  +x \langle i[A,B]\rangle  + x^2 \langle B^2\rangle \cr}$$
This holds for all real $x$ so the quadratic in the last line has either no
real zeros or one double zero; either way, the discriminant is non-positive:
$$\langle i[A,B]\rangle ^2 - 4\langle A^2\rangle \cdot \langle B^2\rangle \phantom{3} \le\phantom{3}0$$
as needed.