# Operators Uncertainty

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

$\hat A$ is an operator.
The uncertainty on $\hat{A}$, $\Delta A$ is defined by:

$$\Delta A=\sqrt{\langle\hat A^2\rangle - \langle\hat A\rangle^2}$$

what is difference between
$\langle\hat A^2\rangle$ and $\langle\hat A\rangle^2$
that leads to Uncertainty Relation between two Operators?

more details:
$$
\langle\hat A^2 \rangle=\langle\psi|\hat A^2|\psi \rangle$$
[What is the name of difference between absolute value of these two complex conjugates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134999/what-is-the-name-of-difference-between-absolute-value-of-these-two-complex-conju)

Comment: The meaning and significance of the notation don't change for different letters used as the operator, so I have removed the redundant $\hat{B}$. Also note the layout differences implied by inline math (single `$`s) and block formatted math (double `$`s) and the need to uses braces `{}` to indicate the range of effect for operators like `\sqrt`.

Comment: thank you but when "that leads to Uncertainty
Relation between two Operators?"
Oops! where is the second operator:D

Comment: Well, you can put $\hat B$, back in but I think that you are mixing up two ideas here. Without writing a commutator between $\hat A$ and $\hat B$, you don't know anything about their relationship.

Comment: "you don't
know anything about their
relationship"
thank you! for your opinion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although Qmechanics's answer is formally complete and correct, there is a more intuitive formulation of this identity that makes it self evident. Consider the operator B which is A minus its expectation value in some state.

$$B =  A - \langle A\rangle $$

Then the expectation value of B is zero in the same state (obviously--- it has been shifted to make it so). The expected value of $B^2$ can be nonzero--- it is a measure of the spread in B in state $\psi$. It is positive, as you can see by the definition of matrix multiplication (or by "inserting the identity in a basis")

$$ \langle B^2 \rangle = \sum_i \langle |B|i\rangle\langle i|B\rangle $$

The last thing on the right is the sum of positive quatities of the form $c^*c$. If you now reexpress the expectation value of $B^2$ in terms of A,

$$ \langle B^2 \rangle = \langle (A-\langle A\rangle)^2\rangle = \langle A^2\rangle - 2 \langle A\langle A\rangle \rangle + \langle A\rangle^2 = \langle A^2\rangle - \langle A\rangle^2 $$

This manipulation justifies this thing.

Answer (score 8):

1. $\langle\hat A\rangle$ is the [expectation value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_value_%28quantum_mechanics%29) of $\hat A$.
2. $\langle\hat A\rangle^2$ is the square of item 1.
3. $\langle\hat A^2\rangle$ is the expectation value of $\hat A^2=\hat A \hat A$.

Item 2 and 3 do not have to be equal.

If $\hat A$ is [selfadjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator), then it is possible to show

1. that the expectation value $\langle\hat A\rangle~\in~\mathbb{R}$ is real, and
2. that $\langle\hat A^2\rangle ~\geq~ \langle\hat A\rangle^2$.

Comment: thank you
"2. $\langle\hat A^2\rangle ~\geq~ \langle\hat A\rangle^2$."

so when $\langle\hat A^2\rangle \approx \langle\hat A\rangle^2$.
$\Delta A$ should be equal zero

Comment: could you please Explain with equation that what is difference between  expectation value of:
1. $\langle\hat A\rangle$ 
2. $\langle\hat A^2\rangle$

regards that $\langle\psi|\hat A|\psi \rangle=\langle\psi|\psi' \rangle$