# Energy-Time Uncertainty Relation and Virtual Particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, time, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, virtual-particles

I've come across a hole in my understanding.

Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle can be expressed in terms of energy and time as

$$ \Delta E \, \Delta t \geq \frac{\hbar}{2} $$

where $\Delta E$ is the uncertainty in a particle's energy and $\Delta t$ is the time period over which this measurement is taken.

However, I know that the existence of virtual particles violating the law of conservation of energy is explained by this relation but on the surface, it does not make sense.

To explain, it is said that virtual particles (pairs) can "pop" into existence in the vacuum as long as they disappear (annihilate) within a time $t$.  This is put down to the uncertainty relation given above.  However, the uncertainty relation given above states that the uncertainty in a virtual particle's energy can be arbitrarily high for arbitrarily high times as long as their product exceeds $\frac{\hbar}{2}$.

I have seen a different relation given below which makes sense of this by turning around the inequality sign and getting rid of the $\Delta$ symbols but I do not see how to derive this properly.  Any help would be appreciated as it's annoying me!

$$ E \, \tau \leq \frac{\hbar}{2} $$ where $\tau$ is the particle's lifetime and $E$ is the particle's actual energy now rather than the uncertainty in the energy.

Comment: That sounds really weird to me. I only know the expression $(\Delta x)^2 (\Delta p)^2 \geq \hbar^2/4$. The expression you have is ill-defined since you consider time as an operator in that way. You can try to write the expression I gave to what you write down using classical arguments and I think this can be done as an approximation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is $\Delta t$ in the time-energy uncertainty principle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/)

Comment: Also [Is there an actual proof for the energy-time Uncertainty Principle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259334/)

Comment: @JohnRennie  It doesn't really answer my question, no.  I'm more curious as to how the relation inverts when you consider particle lifetimes and energies rather than energy and temporal uncertainties.  The inversion allows virtual particles and exchange particles to exist for short periods of time.

Comment: The point is that you have misunderstood what the $\Delta t$ means in the equation and that is the source of your confusion. Note also that virtual particles do not pop into existence for a brief time. The reality is more complicated. See for example [Are vacuum fluctuations really happening all the time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/294339/1325).

Comment: @JohnRennie  Okay, what is $\Delta t$?  I am under the impression it is the uncertainty in time, or the time taken to make a measurement of an energy.  But I think this is by-the-by.  I know that this relation is used to illustrate the possibility of energy non-conserving particles and that this model explains the exchange model of forces in QFT.  I'm just stuck in getting from the top equation to the last one. :)

Comment: You need to read the questions I linked to understand what $\Delta t$ means. It is surprisingly complicated and too complicated to explain in a comment.