# Uncertainty principle in relativistic quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, energy, time, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In Walter Greiner book about relativistic quantum mechanics, he writes the uncertainty relations for 4-position and 4-momentum in a neat way as:

$$[p^\mu, x^\nu] = i\hbar \eta^{\mu\nu}{\bf 1}$$

with Minkowski sign convention $(+,-,-,-)$.
This gives manifestly all the uncertainty relations we want.
But here, time is just a coordinate, so how do we interpret the commutation relation between time and energy?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259334/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/220697/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic
Thank you very much, that was super helpful ^_^

Comment: The takeaway that I took from my 2015 post, which Qmechanic linked above, is that in a covariant treatment of relativistic quantum mechanics, time can be an operator, and it is instead proper time which is just a parameter. The notation you cite from Greiner's book suggests that's what he's doing. Maybe I'll take a look at Greiner.