# Proof of Time-Energy-Uncertainty $\Delta H\frac{\Delta A}{|\frac{d}{dt}\langle A(t)\rangle|}\geq\frac{\hbar}{2}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

I am interested in mathematically proving the time-energy uncertainty relation by Mandelstamm-Tamm in a system seen in the Schrödinger-Picture (time-dependent states but time-independent operators). Let this system be prepared in the state $|\Psi(t)\rangle$.

Let $A$ be a time-independent operator (i.e. not explicitly depending on t) and let $H$ be the Hamiltonian of the system. I want to prove that

$$\Delta H\frac{\Delta A}{|\frac{d}{dt}\langle A(t)\rangle|}\geq\frac{\hbar}{2}$$
where $\Delta A:=\sqrt{\langle A^2\rangle-\langle A\rangle^2}$ denotes the standard deviation of $A$ (and for $H$ analogously). I use the following Hamiltonian:
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(x)=-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2+V(x)$$
where $p=-i\hbar\nabla$ denotes the impulse operator, $x$ the impulse operator and $V:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ a given potential.

I wish to use the general uncertainty principle, which states that
$$\Delta H\Delta A\geq\frac{1}{2}|\langle[H,A]\rangle|=\frac{1}{2}|\langle\Psi(t)|[H,A]|\Psi(t)\rangle|=\,\stackrel{?}{\cdots}\,=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left|\frac{d}{dt}\langle\Psi(t)|A|\Psi(t)\rangle\right|$$
from which we could deduce the desired by dividing by $\frac{\hbar}{2}|\frac{d}{dt}\langle A\rangle|$ on both sides.

I have problems at the question mark and I cannot figure out how to move on with
$$[H,A]|\Psi(t)\rangle=(HA-AH)|\Psi(t)\rangle=\frac{\hbar}{2m}(A\nabla^2|\Psi(t)\rangle-\nabla^2A|\Psi(t)\rangle)$$
since there is not time derivative $\frac{d}{dt}$ involved here. Did I use the wrong Hamiltonian or did I oversee something?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that $A(t):=U^\dagger AU$ with $U=U(t)=\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}Ht\right)$ (I want $H$ to be time-independent).

EDIT 2: I was pointed to the relation
$$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}A(t)=[A(t),H]$$
but I am not sure if I can use this in my system and I also tried to use this to find
\begin{align*}
\Delta A\Delta H&\geq\frac{1}{2}|\langle\Psi(t)|[H,A]|\Psi(t)\rangle|=\frac{1}{2}|\langle\Psi(t)|\left(-i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}A(t)\right)|\Psi(t)\rangle| \\
&= \frac{\hbar}{2}|\langle\Psi(t)|\frac{d}{dt}A(t)|\Psi(t)\rangle|\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{\hbar}{2}\left|\frac{d}{dt}\langle\Psi(t)|A(t)|\Psi(t)\rangle\right|
\end{align*}
where I am not sure about interchanging $\frac{d}{dt}$ with $\langle\cdot\rangle$ in the last step.

Comment: Isn't this simply the [Heisenberg equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture#Mathematical_details)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259334/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Tip: [Let's not have posts look like revision histories](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/2451).