# Why does the universe follow the uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, universe, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I have been thinking about this question for quiet a long time but, couldn't make up an answer myself. Usually when someone asks about why a system is the way it is we answer it by saying that it is the most stable lowest energy state(to know about why a system should be at its lowest energy state for its stability click [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87371/why-a-system-should-be-at-its-lowest-energy-state-for-its-stability)). But, what about the uncertainty principle? What benefit does the universe/nature get by following this principle?

Comment: why are systems most stable at the lowest energy state?

Comment: @gregsan I thought about this question that you asked while I was typing this one and I have just posted another question on it before you commented.

Comment: here, this should interest you http://lesswrong.com/lw/99c/transcript_richard_feynman_on_why_questions/

Comment: I think that you're carrying the minumum energy explanation too far...

Comment: @gregsan I had seen the whole video interview of R.P Feynman sir.

Comment: When you say _Why does the universe
follow the uncertainty
principle?_ do you mean if the Universe as an object has uncertainty or about the physical laws?

Comment: I mean why the universe works in a way such that one is not able to accurately measure the momentum and position of an object(subatomic) simultaneously?

Comment: Uncertainty principle and lowest energy state are not correlated. Perhaps it is better you read some books and/or attend some courses of thermodynamics and quantum physics, then ask this kind of question.

Comment: From @Anixx 's answer I understand that since there are several different physical interpretations of the uncertainty principle there cannot be a unique answer for this question.At this stage with all these different interpretations is this question useless? Can someone answer this based on the interpretation that they support or like?

Comment: The HEP is the same for every interpretation. So the answer will be the same.

Comment: I've seen an argument that the presences of the uncertainty principle allows the elimination of some possible paradoxes and contradictions (of the Zeno's Arrow type).

Answer (score 4):

The uncertainty principle is a mathematical consequence of wave behaviour. It is true for sound waves, electrical signals, radio waves, etc. Anywhere you might want to work with Fourier transforms.

Let's say you want to send a pulse via a radio wave. Furthermore, lets say you make the amplitude of the pulse a Gaussian function with time:

$f(t) \sim e^{-\alpha t^2}$

This pulse has width $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}}$.

Then in frequency space, the Fourier transform of this function is another Gaussian:

$F(\omega) \sim e^{-\frac{\omega^2}{\alpha}}$

This pulse has width $\sqrt{\alpha}$.

Generally, the more you localize the signal in time, the wider it gets in frequency, and vice versa. A signal having an exact frequency $\omega$ is completley delocalized in time: $\sin\omega \,t$. If we were talking about a particle instead of a radio wave, we would say that the energy of the particle is definite, and therefore its wave function will unchanged for an infinite amount of time.

Comment: No, it is untrue. What is uncertain with radio waves if one does not consider quantum behavior? -1

Comment: The uncertainty principle is the statement that you can't squeeze a signal in frequency domain without spreading it out in the time domain. Holds for radio waves too.

Comment: what? please write an equation so we could see what you are talking about.

Comment: I've edited my response. You can read more about it [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waves/node44.html)
I

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. This can be said in shorter form: any non-periodic function does not have a unique frequency. Yet it does not introduce any uncertainty about the amplitude, energy or location of the wave in the classical domain. The uncertainty in position appears only when we consider the amplitude to determine the probability, which is uniquely quantum feature.

Comment: It most certainly does introduce uncertainty about the location of the wave. The wave packet can't be localized in real space and in wave-vector space simultaneously. You are giving a quantum interpretation to what is a generic property of waves.

Comment: well, this is a consequence of the fact that you choose for "wave vector space" a space that conists only of monochromatic waves. In that case, indeed, you cannot localize a wave packet there because it is not monochromatic! But you can freely extend the phase space to include any wave.

Comment: @lionelbrits   I think you are correct. As always when asking  a "why" question in physics, "problem number one is reduced to problem number two" as a professor of mine used to say. In this case "why quantum mechanics obeys the uncertainty principle" is reduced to "why a probabilistic interpretation of a wave equation describes elementary particles and their interactions" . The answer of course is "because". we hit an axiom.

Comment: @annav heh, the reason I went into physics instead of another science. Unfortunately it's tortoises all the way down.

anixx what can I say? That is kind of the point of a vector space. In quantum mechanics, we would talk about momentum eigenstates. But the principle holds for any wave. You seem to have gotten stuck on the point about plane waves. But any physical wave admits a Fourier expansion, and has a dual description in terms of the wavelengths and phases that makes it up.

Comment: @lionelbrits and there of course no uncertainty in the fourier expansion. Wideness does not mean uncertainty.

Comment: Well, if the fourier expansion contains more than one mode, then $\langle k^2 \rangle - \langle k \rangle ^2 \neq 0$. The same thing we call uncertainty in quantum mechanics we would call standard deviation. The origin of the mathematics is in either case the same.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the interpretation of quantum mechanics you like the most. As they are mathematically equivalent, the question is metaphysical rather than scientific.

Some of the ways to explain:

- There is no uncertainty in the system. The uncertainty is in the observer. By making the measurement the observer introduces the uncertainty because he cannot for sure know his own state due to self-reference. (Bohm interpretation)
- There is no uncertainty in the system, because the measured value actually does not exist. What is real is the wave function, which is always certain (MWI, von Neumann etc)
- The uncertainty is introduced by vacuum fluctuations. Virtual particles of vacuum bombard all real particles so they conduct chaotic motion within certain limits. Vacuum thus can be seen as a medium having lowest possible, but non-zero energy.
- The measured values are densely packed: two or more variables can be stored in 1 bit of information in nature (each carrying less than a bit). As our brain (and most instruments we use) cannot manipulate with amounts of information less than 1 bit, we can measure in one experiment only 1 value for which we use the whole bit while the other part becomes lost.

There are multiple other explanations as well.

Comment: If by "metaphysical" you mean "choice of axioms that allow the formulation of mathematical models which describe observations".

Comment: @anna v mathematical models do not differ.

Answer (score 0):

Physics isn't entitled in answering the question "why" but rather "how". The question "why" is always diverted to philosophy, and some liars use it to make religions.

Comment: Why is it that physics explains the why question until it gets to the most fundamental level and the last one is put to answer by philosophers? Are you trying to say that scientists have not yet arrived at an answer to it?

Comment: Exactly, if we knew, scientist would be doing more usefull things, like fixing the pipes of my kitchen - Quote to Walter Lewin.

Answer (score 0):

> Usually when someone asks about
>   why a system is the way it is we
>   answer it by saying that it is the
>   most stable lowest energy state.

That's a lousy explanation. A system doesn't have to be in the lowest energy state (in that case the Universe would be very boring). In fact, some systems don't even have a definite energy.

To visualize what I've said, you can think of an object which is in a minimum energy state, hence it will be in equilibrium. This is not the case in QM, where an object will experience strange effects like [going through walls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_effect) and [bouncing back when it's going to fall off a cliff](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=new-quantum-weirdness).

> But,
>   what about the uncertainty
>   principle? What benefit does the
>   universe/nature get by following this
>   principle?

I think no benefit. You can derive the HUP from the postulates of QM. Physics is more complicated than the lowest energy principle.

The HUP is an experimental fact which can be deduced from the non-commutativity of QM observables. See [How does non-commutativity lead to uncertainty?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/how-does-non-commutativity-lead-to-uncertainty) and [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle scientific proof](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24116/heisenberg-uncertainty-principle-scientific-proof/).

TIP: *Why* questions in Physics are usually useless.

Comment: How did you came to the conclusion that the universe would have no benefit?

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR Because it doesn't even make sense, as I've stated in the answer. It's like asking _Would the Universe be happier if Newton's law were valid?_ And by your reasoning, every physical law obey make the universe have some _benefit_.

Answer (score 0):

This reply probably would be more suitable as comment, but i'm unable to comment yet, so:
First of all we can't really describe universe as a system that even close to entropy which actually would be a lowest energy and most stable state for universe. So, following from that: universe is unstable, and as it's unstable there is no really a problem for Universe to follow uncertainty.