# Work done relation to potential energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, potential-energy

I know work done is negative of change in potential energy, I.e., $W=-(∆U)$.

It means that Work done against a force (or work done on a system) increases its potential energy.
And Work done by a force (or work done by the system) decreases its potential energy.

But why this is so that an internal force (by internal force I mean that a force created under a system) will always tend to decrease the potential energy of the system while the external force increase the potential energy of the system?

Comment: This formula is only valid in specific cases, where the kinetic energy is zero. Rather use the more general formula of the mechanical energy balance: $$K_1+U_1+W=K_2+U_2$$

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by your final sentence?

Comment: @sammygerbil    Let's take an example of system of 2 point charges.One be the source charge q and another one be the test charge q' which is +ve.
The charge q' will displace towards external force.

If source charge is +ve it will repel the q' charge.I have to do +ve work to bring q' from infinity(where PE=0) to finite separation which will increase the PE.
If source charge is -ve it will attract the q' charge.I have to do +ve work to displace q' to infinity.So q will do -ve same work t0 bring q' from infinity(where PE=0).-ve work will lower down the PE.

Comment: So Internal force decreases the PE of system whereas
External Force increase the PE of system

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note, that you are totally skipping the kinetic Energy $T$ part. The total energy of a system is given by $E=T+U$.
There are several examples of systems which build up potential Energy over time.
Some examples are:

- The mass of a pendulum is constantly cycling the total energy between kinetic and potential energy
- Objects orbiting a center of mass are generally moving on elliptic orbits. Which are also cycling between potential and kinetic energy.
- A collision of 2 comets can give one of them enough speed to leave the solar system. Thus building up potential energy for eternity.

But your observation does have a valid point. Physical systems tend to go towards lower energy states on their own. So many states which have high potential energy (e.g. a ball on a hill) are unstable. There are several additional questions which cover this topic:

- [Why does the nature always prefer low energy and maximum entropy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47253/why-does-the-nature-always-prefer-low-energy-and-maximum-entropy?rq=1)
- [Why does a system try to minimize potential energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113092/why-does-a-system-try-to-minimize-potential-energy)
- [Why a system should be at its lowest energy state for its stability?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87371/why-a-system-should-be-at-its-lowest-energy-state-for-its-stability)

Comment: Is this answering the question?

Comment: @Steeven I see your point, on a second thought I vote to flag this question as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of $W=-\Delta U$ has been misinterpreted here. The OP states it as

> It means that Work done against a force (or work done on a system) increases its potential energy. And Work done by a force (or work done by the system) decreases its potential energy.

This is false. What this equation means is that the work done *by a conservative force* is equal to the negative change in potential energy *associated with that conservative force*. This can easily be seen by using the definition of potential energy and work. Considering a conservative force $\mathbf F$ with associated potential energy $U$:
$$\mathbf F=-\nabla U$$
The work done by this force along some path starting at position $\mathbf{r_1}$ and ending at postion $\mathbf{r_2}$ is then given by the line integral along this path
$$W=\int_{\mathbf{r_1}\rightarrow\mathbf{r_2}}\mathbf F\cdot\text d\mathbf x=-\int_{\mathbf{r_1}\rightarrow\mathbf{r_2}}\nabla U\cdot\text d\mathbf x$$
Using the fundamental theorem of calculus we arrive at
$$W=-\left[U(\mathbf{r_2})-U(\mathbf{r_1})\right]=-\Delta U$$

Therefore, this equation is only concerned with thinking about the work done by conservative forces and how that effects the potential energy associated with those forces.