# Tightly bound energy configuration for nucleons?

Tags: energy, mass, nuclear-physics, fusion, binding-energy

In fusion, why are nucleons of the product nucleus tightly bound and in a lower energy configuration than the nucleons in the reactant nuclei?  I think the reason a large amount of energy is released is due to the nucleons of the product nucleus being in a lower energy state as compared to the nucleons of the reactant nuclei...
Is this theory correct?
Please clarify this doubt with as much detail as possible.... :(

Comment: Yes , it is the release of energy, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion#Process  see

Comment: But that energy release is due to what?

Comment: In all of physics observations ( from thermodynamics to quantum) if there is a possible lower energy state  where conservation laws are obeyed, systems go to the lowest energy states, and this is in all the models describing the data.

Comment: But the reason for energy release?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87371/why-a-system-should-be-at-its-lowest-energy-state-for-its-stability    https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64146/the-preference-for-low-energy-states

Comment: I know that these systems have a lower energy state but how does this cause an energy release?

Comment: from conservation of energy for the total system. It is a law, i.e. it comes from observations of data and has not been falsified up to now.