# A detail from matrix mechanics interpretation of uncertainty

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, fourier-transform

This question is a small step removed from two earlier questions about the uncertainty relation in the QM context. knzhou's [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240543/is-there-something-behind-non-commuting-observables) touches on the point, and L. Motl's link-answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/how-does-non-commutativity-lead-to-uncertainty) is a little closer.

The passage from Wikipedia in relevant part is (italics added):

> "When a state is measured, it is projected onto an eigenstate in the basis of the relevant observable. For example, if a particle's position is measured, then the state amounts to a position eigenstate. This means that the state is not a momentum eigenstate, however, *but rather it can be represented as a sum of multiple momentum basis eigenstates.* In other words, the momentum must be less precise. This precision may be quantified by the standard deviations..."

Well, the crucial step is missing I think. I understand the wave-mechanical explanation well, and I appreciate that different observables are associated with different eigenstates.

Can someone fill in these two points or suggest a reference for:

1. In what sense can a position eigenstate be represented as a sum of momentum eigenstates? Maybe a homely example would do here...
2. How does the math of a position eigenstate represented by multiple momentum eigenstates translate into the product of variances?

If the answer is too involved a reference would be great.

Comment: Position and momentum eigenstates are connected by Fourier transform.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: Maybe I misinterpret "represented." You are saying they are FT pairs...then a position eigenstate corresponds to a FT that is a sum of multiple momentum e-states. Is that accurate?

Comment: It is correct. $|x\rangle=\int d^3p \langle p|x\rangle|p \rangle$ or, if you are not familiar with the ket notation : $\psi_{x_0}(x)=\delta(x-x_0)=\int d^3p \widehat{\psi_{x_0}}(p) e^{ipx}$ where : $\psi_{x_0}(x)$ is the eigenfunction of the position in representation x, and $e^{-ipx}$ is eigenfunction of the momentum operator in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me provide a slightly different derivation, which emphasize the Fourier transform aspect of the relation between the $x$ and $p$ representations.

Let $\vert p\rangle$ be a state with definite momentum.  Physically, we know that such a state is a plane wave so that, in the $x$-representation:
$$
\psi_p(x)=\langle x\vert p\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}e^{ipx/\hbar}\tag{1}
$$
Conversely it follows that 
$$
\langle p\vert x\rangle := \psi_x(p)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}e^{-ipx/\hbar} \tag{2}
$$
Somewhat informally, the $\vert p\rangle$ states are eigenstates of a hermitian operator $\hat p$ so they form a complete basis, with expansion of unity
$$
1=\int dp \vert p\rangle \langle p \vert\, .
$$
Likewise.  $\vert x\rangle$ are eigenstate are eigenstates of $\hat x$ so
$$
1=\int dx \vert x\rangle \langle x \vert\, .
$$

Thus, to your question 1:
$$
\vert x\rangle = \int dp \vert p\rangle \langle p \vert x\rangle = 
\int dp \vert p\rangle  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}e^{-ipx/\hbar}
$$
and more generally
$$
\langle p\vert\psi\rangle: = \psi(p) = 
\int dx \langle p\vert x\rangle \langle x \vert\psi\rangle \,
=\int dx   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}e^{-ipx/\hbar} \psi(x)
$$
and conversely $\psi(x)$ is the (inverse) Fourier transform of $\psi(p)$.  Note that the normalization of (1) and (2) is ``symmetrical" in that both the direct and inverse Fourier transform carry a factor of $1/\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}$; this is not the usual convention of many math textbooks.

To your question 2: there are "classical" uncertainty relations related to product of variances for pairs of variables related by Fourier transforms like $p$ and $x$ (or $E$ and $t$) but of course these are not quantum in any sense. In this case they simply express that to localize a wave packet in space requires an increasingly wider distribution of the conjugate momentum. There is nothing quantum in this product of variances.

The *quantum* uncertainty relations, related to products of variances of non-commutating operators, is fundamentally different as it arises as a result of quantum non commutativity of operators.

Comment: The quantum version is a formal inequality involving operators: $\Delta A\Delta B\ge \frac{1}{2}\vert \langle [\hat A,\hat B]\rangle$ and in general the average value of the commutator will be state-dependent.  In the specific case of $\hat x$ and $\hat p$, the commutator is $i\hbar$ so state-independent.  The $1/2$ factor is important and the h.o. ground state is state for which the strict equality holds.  The classical version is an informal relation $\Delta x\Delta p\sim \hbar$ which only makes sense for conjugate variables.

Comment: The classical result depends on the definition of width.  Take $\sin(x)/x$;  do you defined width as distance between first $0$'s or at width at $1/2$max?  Also the time-energy version $\Delta E\Delta t$ is tricky in QM because time is not an operator.  I have to go... stay well.

Comment: Writing the question out helped me answer it, so I deleted.

Comment: @daniel I'm tight for time right now but will update/edit my answer within 72hrs to add a short discussion on the problem of properly defining the width in the classical context.

Comment: OK look forward to it, and I do think your answer is fine as is.