# Uncertainty Principle with the corresponding operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, observables

Why does the corresponding operator do not commute if there is uncertainty related to two observables A and B that states $\Delta A\,\Delta B > 0 $ ?

Comment: by construction of the theory. The HUP is the result of noncommuting operators. the theory , QM, fits the data

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10362/

Comment: I decided to remove my answer as the problem involves some delicate issues of spectral theory of unbounded operators and I have no time enough to enter into the relevant details now. I hope to do it later.