# How is the uncertainty principle related to the non-commutativity of the multiplication of operators in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

The way I understand the uncertainty principle is that it's not even really about quantum mechanics specifically -- it's just a property of waves.  e.g. A periodic wave doesn't even *have* a well defined position, so in order for wave-function to have a well-defined position, we have to represent it as the superposition of many different waves which will have varying momentums.  But what's this got to do with multiplication of operators not being commutative?  It makes sense that there would be some limit to how well can define wave properties that are linked in this way, but what does it matter what order we do things in?

Edit: This question is not the same as the one linked.  That question is about the algebra.  My question is about how the algebra is related to the geometry of wave mechanics.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10362/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24116/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic This question is definitely not a duplicate of the cited page. The OP is clearly trying to understand a non trivial conceptual problem whose solution has no relation with the properties or algebra of operators found in the answers to that question. Even a comparison of the formulation of the two titles could suggest some caution before  classifying the present question s a duplicate. I am going to propose  to reopen this question.

Comment: It’s not a duplicate.  That questions is much broader than mine.